# how to use arraycollection in web service

Tags: .net, apache-flex

I am passing array collection from flex to web service, and now that array collection want to use in asp.net web service.

suppose i have passed one array collection, and based on that array collection i want fetch value from database and want to generate report and returning path to flex.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried anything? if, what you tried? are you using fluorine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i could not able to use arraycollection value in web service (asp.net side) so i change the passing parameter...now passing comma separated string as a parameter and in web service split that string.

my problem solved anyways.

Thanks M.S.Nayak.

Thanks
Subhash